# Xamarin Android conflicting with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Im trying to create a Fragment and add it to a Activity using the `FragmentManager`.

The problem is i get a compile error. It appears that `MvxFragment` inherits from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` and `MvxFragmentActivity` inherits from `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity` that in turns inherits from `Android.App.FragmentActivity`

This means the FragmentManager expects a `Android.App.Fragment` but MvvmCross uses `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`

How do i get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MvvmCross has support for both `Fragment` and `V4.Fragment`. To use the first you should only install the `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging`. When using V4 you should install the `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging` and 'MvvmCross.Droid.V7.AppCompat'.

As base for your activity you could use `MvxAppCompatActivity` or the `MvxCachingFragmentActivity`.

Comment: I think i figured it out so i went with FullFragging and it seems to be working now. Everything is just very confusing in the Android world with V4 needing V7 and API level this and API level that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Depending on the API level you are targeting it might be better to go with V7 support.

Comment: For others who are confused depending on what you use you need to get the `FragmentManager` from either `.FragmentManager` or `.SupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Im targeting API level 15 as my minimum? Which is Xamarin.Android 4.0.3

Comment: Yeah, so with API 15 as minimum it is better to go for V7 with AppCompat. This will enable you to use Material design on older versions of Android. You can find a sample here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: Thank you, i will take a look at it later and try and convert to it.

Comment: Does the MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging package still exist? It doesn't show up in the package manager. (I am using MvvmCross 4.4.0)

Comment: This has been moved to `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment` https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment